# javascript will not generate from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i believe I have a working javascript functions that should generate a list of questions and choices on a single page, but will not run and no errors are running on chrome console.

-At the moment I have two functions function createQuestions & createChoices
-I do have some extra variables at the top for the later stages, but right now I just want to display the questions and answers.

```js
//end screen counters
var incorrectCounter = 0;
var correctCounter = 0;
var notAnsweredCounter = 0;
var quiz = $('#quiz');
var index = 0;

//empty array to push each selected answer to 
var userGuess = [];
var answerKey = ["html", "css", "jquery", "none of the above"];



//function that runs the questions and possible choices at start up
$(window).ready(function startUp() {

  //all questions and choices are in a large array
  var questionArray = [{
    questions: "what did we learn in week 1?",
    //smaller array within the large array for each possible answer for each question
    choices: ["html", "css", "jquery", "javascript", "none of the above"]
  }, {
    questions: "what did we learn in week 2?",
    choices: ["html", "css", "jquery", "javascript", "none of the above"]
  }, {
    questions: "what did we learn in week 4?",
    choices: ["html", "css", "jquery", "javascript", "none of the above"]
  }, {
    questions: "what did we learn in week 5?",
    choices: ["html", "css", "jquery", "javascript", "none of the above"]
  }];

  function createQuestions(index) {
    var trivia = $('<div>', {
      id: 'question'
    });

    var header = $('<h2>Question ' + (index + 1) + ':</h2>');
    trivia.append(header);

    var question = $('<p>').append(questions[index].question);
    trivia.append(question);

    var radioButtons = createChoices(index);
    trivia.append(radioButtons);

    return trivia;
    index++;

  }

  function createChoices(index) {
    var radioList = $("<ul>");
    var item;
    var input = "";
    for (i = 0; i < questionArray[index].choices.length; i++) {
      item = $('<li>');
      input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + ' />';
      input += question[index].choices[i];
      item.append(input);
      radioList.append(item);
    }
    return radioList;
    index++;
  }

  //End of the start up function
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Trivia Game: Easy Ver.</title>
  <link href="assets/images">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <!--Here is the jquery code -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js" integrity="sha256-iT6Q9iMJYuQiMWNd9lDyBUStIq/8PuOW33aOqmvFpqI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!--Start of main container -->
  <div id="maincontainer" class="container">
    <h1>Basic Trivia Game</h1>

    <div>
      Time Remaining:
      <p id="timerDiv">00:00 Test</p>
    </div>

    <div class="container weekDiv">

      <p id="quiz">still a test?</p>
    </div>

    <div>
      <button id="submit">Submit Answers test</button>
    </div>
    <br />

    <!--End of main container -->
  </div>

  <!--Test for adding a footer via javascript -->
  <div id="footer">
    HTML test, will be replaced (footer)
  </div>


  <script src="assets/javascript/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Could you use a template library instead of generating it by hand? mustache for example.

Comment: the prof never said we couldn't but i don't think that's the purpose of the assignment

Comment: Will you be generating these questions one by one?

Comment: You just define the function "createQuestions" but never call it.

Comment: ideally once the function is called it will generate 1 question and 1 choice list from the questionArray and i just noticed i did not call the functions im attempting to console.log them and get to display with little success

Comment: BTW, `index++;` should be placed before the return statement.

Comment: @ChristianA @user2970115 If you call the function, you get this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: questions is not defined`

Comment: Here are some problems I found while playing with your code: 1) You use `questions` several places instead of `questionArray`. 2) The `index++` lines are after the return statement. 3) WHY are you incrementing `index`? It's not going to update that number outside the function. 4) Your `for` loop creates a global variable because you aren't declaring `i` properly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing some function calls and not calling the correct variable.

try this:

```
//end screen counters
var incorrectCounter = 0;
var correctCounter = 0;
var notAnsweredCounter = 0;
var quiz = $('#quiz');
var index = 0;

//empty array to push each selected answer to 
var userGuess = [];
var answerKey = ["html", "css", "jquery", "none of the above"];


//function that runs the questions and possible choices at start up
$(window).ready(function startUp() {

  //all questions and choices are in a large array
  var questionArray = [{
    questions: "what did we learn in week 1?",
    //smaller array within the large array for each possible answer for each question
    choices: ["html", "css", "jquery", "javascript", "none of the above"]
  }, {
    questions: "what did we learn in week 2?",
    choices: ["html", "css", "jquery", "javascript", "none of the above"]
  }, {
    questions: "what did we learn in week 4?",
    choices: ["html", "css", "jquery", "javascript", "none of the above"]
  }, {
    questions: "what did we learn in week 5?",
    choices: ["html", "css", "jquery", "javascript", "none of the above"]
  }];

  function createQuestions() {
    var trivia = $('<div>', {
      id: 'question'
    });

    var header = $('<h2>Question ' + (index + 1) + ':</h2>');
    trivia.append(header);

    var question = $('<p>').text(questionArray[index].questions);
    trivia.append(question);

    var radioButtons = createChoices(index);
    trivia.append(radioButtons);

    quiz.append(trivia);
  }

  function createChoices(index) {
    var radioList = $("<ul>");
    var item;
    var input = "";
    for (i = 0; i < questionArray[index].choices.length; i++) {
      item = $('<li>');
      input = '<input type="radio" name="answer" value=' + i + ' />';
      input += questionArray[index].choices[i];
      item.append(input);
      radioList.append(item);
    }
    return radioList;
  }

  createQuestions();

  //End of the start up function
});
```